# Difficulty with second domain in an SPF Record (not allowed use email addy)

Tags: email, spf

I'm kinda out of my element here so please forgive me. I have read and googled several spf post and troubleshooting tips but I can't quite figure out what I'm missing.

My test email is failing MailTester.com...well sorta. 6.5/10.

Googling why I am getting dinged -3 it appears my spf record needs to allow the domain emails are being sent from. (bombomb).

So I modified on bluehost my spf txt record adding bombbomb.

```
v=spf1 a mx include:websitewelcome.com include:bbemaildelivery.com ~all
```

But I must be doing something wrong as I still get

> [SenderId] domain.com does not allow your server [IP Addy] to use john@domain.com --where john@domain.com is my actual email addy.

---

Edit.

Just read a post that said this error can happen if the spf has too many redirects but I'm not sure if that applies to my situation?

Comment: [What is the actual domain name? And what is the actual IP address of the sending mail server?](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/126632)

Comment: @MichaelHampton My apologies didn't realize they would be needed. The domain is zimmermanteamak.com and the IP is 209.51.162.180

Comment: Hmm. It looks like you're hitting the 10-lookup limit due to the poor design of websitewelcome.com's SPF records (not to mention the poor design of their mail systems). Are you sure you really need this?

Comment: No..that was pre-existing. I'll check into the need of it. For my education how did you do that...I mean how can I learn to self serv next time?

Comment: Why, I just looked up _their_ SPF records!